# In my iOS app, is there any reason to set the HttpOnly and Secure flags for the session cookie?

Tags: ios, security, mobile

I know it's a good security practice for web applications to set both the HttpOnly and Secure flags for session cookies, but I'm not convinced it's necessary for iOS apps that are written in native code (in other words - no Javascript is being used).

Since Javascript isn't being used, is there any way somebody can access the session cookie as a result of the HttpOnly flag not being set?

If the flags should be set, what's the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: As you say. these flags are JS-related. A native app would not use JavaScript, right?

Answer (score 2):

If your users will only ever be using a native iOS app and not a web browser, then no you do not need to set those flags, as long as the native app knows to handle the cookie securely.  Those flags are intended to indicate to the client application (usually a web browser) that it should only submit the cookie under certain conditions, tyically that the connection is using `https`.  It would be the native app's responsibility to only submit the cookie when appropriate.  If there are conditions where the cookie would *not* be handled securely and there may be ambiguity, then you should use them.

Regardless, I would use them for future compatibility, and the fact that they're easy to set.  Chances are good that it won't matter now, but you never know what the future will bring and how your app will evolve.

Comment: You sold me in the second paragraph. Future compatibility! That's reason enough. Thanks for the explanation!